# Add highlight or marker function to html canvas w/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on making a nuclear physics webgame. I have created a nuclide chart on a canvas. I manually created every isotope and inputted their corresponding isotope name. A sample is below, as there are over 500 isotopes. I had to do this manually because the "grid" has to be in the form of the normal nuclide chart. The thing I need to do next is create some sort of function that will either highlight an isotope when its clicked on, or put a "marker" on the isotope when clicked on. And unhighlight or move the marker when a different isotope is clicked on. I've been at this for quite some time, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
  // hydrogen
  ctx.fillRect(21, 960, 25, 25);
  ctx.fillRect(46, 960, 25, 25);
  ctx.strokeRect(71, 960, 25, 25);
  ctx.strokeRect(96, 960, 25, 25);
  ctx.strokeRect(121, 960, 25, 25);
  ctx.strokeRect(146, 960, 25, 25);
  ctx.strokeRect(171, 960, 25, 25);
  //
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillText("1H", 23, 980, 15, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillText("2H", 48, 980, 15, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText("3H", 73, 980, 15, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText("4H", 98, 980, 15, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText("5H", 123, 980, 15, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText("6H", 148, 980, 15, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText("7H", 173, 980, 15, 15);
```

Comment: Maybe give every isotope a *hitbox*. Like a invisible square around your isotope. Then listen for the `click` event on the canvas and check if the coordinates of the mouse match any bounds of the hitboxes.

Comment: I've never used a hitbox before, how would I write that?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I think you're making things more difficult than they need to be. Canvas 2D is an example of [immediate mode rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)) which makes interactivity like you describe non-trivial. Unless you really want to build a custom UI system from scratch, I'd recommend using DOM nodes for your isotopes + CSS styling + JS for interactivity. Or use a library on top of canvas like [EaselJS](https://www.createjs.com/easeljs) which gives you mouse interaction and an object hierarchy for representing your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created these functions to draw a circle onto my canvas and be able to track mouse position, test for if it's on the circle, and then listen for click down and up to be able to drag it. If there are other draw elements in the project, in this instance for me it's all 520 of my isotopes, you just need to put that code inside of your redraw function, or else everything else disappears after moving the cirlce

```
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// used to calc canvas position relative to window
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }
canvas.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// save relevant information about shapes drawn on the canvas
var shapes=[];
// define one circle and save it in the shapes[] array
shapes.push( {x:300, y:275, radius:10} );
var isDragging=false;
var startX,startY;

// hold the index of the shape being dragged (if any)
var selectedShapeIndex;

// draw the shapes on the canvas
drawAll();

// listen for mouse events
canvas.onmousedown=handleMouseDown;
canvas.onmousemove=handleMouseMove;
canvas.onmouseup=handleMouseUp;
canvas.onmouseout=handleMouseOut;

// given mouse X & Y (mx & my) and shape object
// return true/false whether mouse is inside the shape
function isMouseInShape(mx,my,shape){
    if(shape.radius){
        // this is a circle
        var dx=mx-shape.x;
        var dy=my-shape.y;
        // math test to see if mouse is inside circle
        if(dx*dx+dy*dy<shape.radius*shape.radius){
            // yes, mouse is inside this circle
            return(true);
        }
    }
    // the mouse isn't in any of the shapes
    return(false);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // calculate the current mouse position
    startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    // test mouse position against all shapes
    // post result if mouse is in a shape
    for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){
        if(isMouseInShape(startX,startY,shapes[i])){
            // the mouse is inside this shape
            // select this shape
            selectedShapeIndex=i;
            // set the isDragging flag
            isDragging=true;
            // and return (==stop looking for
            //     further shapes under the mouse)
            return;
        }
    }
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
    // return if we're not dragging
    if(!isDragging){return;}
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // the drag is over -- clear the isDragging flag
    isDragging=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
    // return if we're not dragging
    if(!isDragging){return;}
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // the drag is over -- clear the isDragging flag
    isDragging=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
    // return if we're not dragging
    if(!isDragging){return;}
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // calculate the current mouse position
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    // how far has the mouse dragged from its previous mousemove position?
    var dx=mouseX-startX;
    var dy=mouseY-startY;
    // move the selected shape by the drag distance
    var selectedShape=shapes[selectedShapeIndex];
    selectedShape.x+=dx;
    selectedShape.y+=dy;
    // clear the canvas and redraw all shapes
    drawAll();
    // update the starting drag position (== the current mouse position)
    startX=mouseX;
    startY=mouseY;
}

// clear the canvas and
// redraw all shapes in their current positions
function drawAll(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){
        var shape=shapes[i];
        if(shape.radius){
            // it's a circle
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(shape.x,shape.y,shape.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
            ctx.fillStyle=shape.color;
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Down here I've created a demo of how you would do such a thing like creating a *hitbox*. The hitbox will be represented by a square that has a random position on the canvas when the script runs.

In the script we use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` event listeners to determine when the user presses and releases the mouse. On mousedown the `x` and `y` coordinates of the mouse are calculated relative to the size of the canvas. By calculating it this way you can get the exact pixel on the canvas that has been clicked upon. It then stores this value in a global variable.

You'll need to know the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` of the hitbox because you'll want to determine if the `x` and `y` of the click is within the square that is the hitbox.

In the demo below the view is re-rendered whenever you click and release the click. The `mouseData` state changes en will show that in the new render. The render then evaluates for the hitbox if the `mouseData.position` coordinates are inside of the box and changes the color based on that evaluation.

Then releasing the mouse triggers another re-render changing the clicked state to false and showing the original state of the hitbox.

So this is basically what it is, a square of coordinates which detects if the clicked pixel is inside that square and does something if it is.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const squareSideSize = 50;

canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

// Stores data on the mouseclick.
let mouseData = {
  clicked: false,
  position: [] // Here we will store the x and y of click as [ x, y ]
}

/**
 * Generates random number between min and max value.
 * Just for the purpose of drawing the hitbox.
 */
const getRandomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

/**
 * Returns an array with x and y coordinates
 * based on the click event.
 */
const getMousePositionOnCanvas = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
  const canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = clientX - canvasRect.left;
  const y = clientY - canvasRect.top;
  return [ x, y ];
};

/**
 * Determines if the x and y from the click is within
 * the x, y, width and height of the square.
 * Returns true or false.
 */
const isInHitbox = ([ x, y ], square) => (
  (x >= square.x && x <= square.x + square.width) &&
  (y >= square.y && y <= square.y + square.height)
);

/**
 * Create random square.
 * This square has an x and y position as well
 * as a width and height. The x and y are created 
 * to enchance the demonstration.
 */
const square = {
  x: getRandomInt(0, canvas.width - squareSideSize),
  y: getRandomInt(0, canvas.height - squareSideSize),
  width: squareSideSize,
  height: squareSideSize
};

// Listen for mousedown and update the click position.
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  mouseData.clicked = true; // Set clicked state to true.
  mouseData.position = getMousePositionOnCanvas(event); // Get the click position relative to the canvas.
  render(); // Render with clicked state.
});

// Listen for mousemove and update the position.
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  if (mouseData.clicked === true) { // Only act if clicked.
    mouseData.position = getMousePositionOnCanvas(event); // Update mouse position.
    render(); // Render with updated mouse position.
  }
})

// Listen for mouseup and clear the click position.
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
  mouseData.clicked = false; // Set clicked state to false.
  mouseData.position.length = 0; // Reset the positions.
  render(); // Render unclicked state.
}); 

/**
 * Render function which clears and draws on the canvas.
 * Here we determine what to draw according the data we
 * collection from the mouse.
 */
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    const { x, y, width, height } = square; // Get all dimensions of the square.
    const { clicked, position } = mouseData; // Get data of the mouse.
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas for a clean re-render.

    // Default white color.
    context.fillStyle = 'white';

    // Check if the mouse has clicked and if the
    // position is inside the hitbox. Change the color 
    // if a it is true.
    if (clicked === true && isInHitbox(position, square)) {
     context.fillStyle = 'green';
    }

    // Draw the hitbox.
    context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  });
}

// Initial render.
render();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```